# Getting 403 forbidden error after setting up Raspberry pivpn

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn

I have tried chmod making the directory executable and iptables to allow port 1194 forwarding so I don't think it is that. I'm still getting Error 403 Forbidden when trying to access the pivpn gui.

Has anyone been able to fix 403 error with pivpn?